# change div color on mouseenter during timeout - jquery function

Tags: function, html, mouseenter, jquery

Right now I have this code:

```
$('.a').mouseenter(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    clearTimeout($this.data('timerMouseleave'));
    $this.css('border', 'solid 1px #444444')
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    var timer = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
        $this.css('border', 'solid 1px #dddddd')
    }, this), 1000)
    $this.data('timerMouseleave', timer)
}).click(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    $this.css('border', 'solid 1px black')
    $this.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7dXAs/6/

I want to add the red border only in case of entering the div again while the timeout is still on. (if possible, please also include playing sound in this case, for ex. aaa.wav).

I need to keep the rest of this behavior exactly as it is, which means that red border should normally change back to default after the timeout.

**clarification**:

timeout / delay gets triggered after mouseleave and it lasts 1 second.

- current situation: if you enter the div again before 1 second expires, timeout gets removed and then triggered again after another mouseleave
- wanted situation: if you enter the div again before 1 second expires, *border becomes red*, timeout gets removed and then triggered again after another mouseleave

Comment: Please elaborate your question.. It's difficult to understand what you really want..

Comment: Which red border? I don't see anything red in your code.

Comment: Remove the `timerMouseleave` from `.data()` when you're done. This way, if `timerMouseleave` exists in the element's `.data()` it means that the timeout is not due it. (I hope I understood your question correctly)

Comment: I've edited the question. If there is still something unclear please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('.a').mouseenter(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    clearTimeout($this.data('timerMouseleave'));
    if($this.hasClass('hide-timer')){
        $this.css('border', 'solid 1px red')
    } else {
        $this.css('border', 'solid 1px #444444')
    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    var timer = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
        $this.css('border', 'solid 1px #dddddd').removeClass('hide-timer')
    }, this), 1000)
    $this.data('timerMouseleave', timer).addClass('hide-timer')
}).click(function(){
    var $this =  $(this);
    $this.css('border', 'solid 1px black')
    $this.off('mouseenter mouseleave');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fkMRe/)

Comment: Hey Arun, I have one specific question regarding coordinates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811991/mouse-coordinates-for-one-div-displayed-in-another-div-jquery

Comment: Hey Arun, since your help really meant a lot to me, I would like to repay you in some way (one-sided - on me, but would be useful for both of us) - if you have a site / blog / etc and if you are interested in details, I'm here - x_xs1@yahoo.com